# Ubuntu GRUB installation error while installing Ubuntu on MacBook Pro 2019

Tags: 18.04, grub2, macbook-pro

I wanted to dual boot my 2019 MacBook Pro with Ubuntu 18.04.I partitioned my disk to have 50 gb for Ubuntu and 8 Gb for swap.I first installed Ubuntu on a bootable drive.But when I tried installing the Ubuntu on my partition I kept getting GNU GRUB installation error and the installation was failing.When I tried to boot up my laptop I got a black screen with GRUB version 2.02. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The newest Macs can have a SSD that requires a driver that your version of Ubuntu may not have. You should make sure you are installing the latest version of Ubuntu. The versions of macOS available to your Mac have a built‑ in driver for this type of drive. Also, Apple supplies a driver that allows Windows 10 to be installed on this type of drive. If you can not get your version of Ubuntu to install, then you should opt to install Ubuntu to an external drive.